# Query to sort the numbers accordingly to its minimum and maximum value (ranges)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table MASTER table. In master tel is the primary key. Now there are other attributes Own,Typeline,Swt, pool,note,mail,timesoforderins. Now i have to make a rnge of tel according to the attributes

```
Tel        Own  Typeline   Swt   pool   note   
01155      asa   wqw       wk1    aqa     xx
01156      asa   wqw       wk1    aqa     xx
01157      asa   wqw       wk1    aqa     xx
01159      qq    qwe       qwq    ede     xxx
01160      qq    qu        qwq    ede     xxx
01161      qqq   qu        qwq    ede     xxx
01162      qqq   qu        qwq    ede     xxx
01167       qa    qu        qwq    ede    xxx
01169      qa     qu       qw1     ed     xxx
01170      qa     qu       qw1     ed     xx
```

now i want the numbers like......

```
Min_Tel       Max_Tel       Own      Typeline      Swt    pool      note
01155           01157       asa       wqw          wk1     aqa       xx
01159           01159        qq        qwe         qwq     ede       xxx
01160           01160        qq        qu          qwq     ede       xxx
01161           01162        qqq       qu           qwq    ede       xxx
01167           01167        qa        qu          qwq     ede       xxx
01169           01169        qa        qu          qw1     ed       xxx
01170           01170        qa         qu         qw1      ed       xx
```

can any one give me a single query to implement the thing....

Comment: what efforts you have made till now? Is your query showing an error.

Comment: Can any of the "other attributes" ever be NULL, and if they can, how should that be handled? For example, if two consecutive Tel's have all the attributes NULL, are they a single range, or are they two separate, single-row ranges?

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` with `max,min`

```
 SELECT    MIN(tel) AS min_tel,
           MAX(tel) AS max_tel,
           own,typeline,swt,pool,note
    FROM master
    GROUP BY own,
             typeline,swt,pool,note 
    order BY min_tel,max_tel;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bdddf/1

Comment: This won't work if the same combination of "other attributes" appears in non-adjacent rows. This is a "gaps and islands" problem which can't be solved with a single aggregate query.

Comment: @Abir - whenever you report "throwing error", you should also say what the error message is. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

SELECT    MIN(tel) AS min_tel, MAX(tel) AS max_tel,own,typeline,swt,pool,note 
    FROM master   GROUP BY own, typeline,swt,pool,note 
   order BY min_tel,max_tel;

Comment: @Abir - if you want help, you must state **what** error you are getting, not just "throwing error". How do you imagine people can help you if they don't know what the error is?

Comment: @AmmarMousa : please *format* your code. If you don't know how, please find the instructions on this site, and follow them.